# Android - text size on particular resolution - setting programatically

Tags: android

I am programming application, which will be used on various kinds of resolutions, but let's say, we would keep to the density. For medium, high and low I am setting it's own drawables, but it still doesn's solve my problem, so I am wondering, how to set values dependently on actual pixel screen density in Java code?

In this time I have to in XML set smaller letters and smaller textviews to fit it into low resolution screen, on the other hand, high density screen is used from about 60% and text fields are too small. I am wondering if there is some way how to, during the start of the program, in some If loop find out, what the resolution is and then set layout_height and textSize for items I want.

Thanks

edit: Solved myself - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well before moving ahead to set the text size programatically, I recommend you to set the Textsize property's value in dip instead of px. it seems that you have marked the textsize value in px.

Comment: No I have dip textsize value, but still, it doesn't solve the problem for me. I have to change for low resolution the hight of a textEdit for example, and there are boundaries, when textEdit cannot be smaller as I want, it has some default hight (set by wrap_content). But even the content is small, textedit is never smaller. That's why I have to do it programatically

Comment: try this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize(int, float)

Comment: I don't see the solution here. All I want is to find out, how to get actual screen density. e.g. something like this.Screen.getDensity, and then in if loop I would set for each density different settings.

Comment: I would use sp for text. Not dip or px.